# Get the whole of a mwe in one click

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice (on the TeX/LaTeX site)  to have next to the code samples  within the posts some location or word (like "copy all") to click and then get the full code sample selected for copy.

This could prove useful on other sites of stackexchange, as well.

Or is there already such a feature which I overlooked ?

Comment: This is already done for some time now. Martin did it with Greasemonkey but then something happened and there was a security concern. Now it is back again I think.  See for example http://stackapps.com/questions/2553/select-code-block-buttons-script and also http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6183/feature-request-better-support-for-copying-code-from-question-or-answers and also  aand also http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/891/3235

Comment: Wow excuse my amazing storytelling skills :)

Comment: if you use sx.el with emacs, we have this functionality

Comment: @SeanAllred I can't browse with emacs at work, as the installed Emacs wasn't compiled with the suitable library and I can't switch to `ewww` mode. I will try it at home but I must first examine how Emacs handles privacy settings. Be it at home (due to my belief my hard-disk may be distantly spied upon) or, needless to say, at work, I only navigate in private browsing mode.